# QWC2 first install

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client, node-js

I'm trying to install QGIS Web Client 2 (QWC2) following instructions in "Quick start" documentation:
https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/blob/master/doc/QWC2_Documentation.md#quick-start

So, I have successfully executed the qwc2-demo-app by "yarn start". 
The next step tell:

> The final step is to compile a deployable application bundle for production:
>   $ yarn run prod.
>   You can then deploy the contents of the prod folder to your web server root.

I run "yarn run prod" and a folder "prod" is created, but I didn't understand how to use it in my web server.

Comment: have you succeed to config the search via WSGI ?

Answer (score 1):

Running "yarn run prod" will create your actual application inside the prod folder. Now we simply move this folder to your htdocs/root folder so apache or some other webserver will serve it.

That's it, now your new client will be accessible across your network. You should access it on:

```
mycomputerIP:<PortWhereWebserverListens>/prod
```

If this is your first time using the client, you will need a webserver to serve your website.

Comment: yes i have already tried your suggestion, but you only see a blank web page and browser debugger does not report any errors.  Have I forgotten some other step?

Comment: Well did you got the requirements right? Because in the documentation it says you need a working QGIS server and a web server.

Comment: Yes I did. I have  both Apache2 and QGIS 3  srv  working on Ubuntu 18. But I think problem is before I running "yarn run prod", because in the "prod" folder there are'nt  themes.json and themesConfig.json files.
So, probably  I'm doing something wrong  in "customize and configure" application. Have you a better step by step guide about  "customizing"  ??

Comment: Hmm, well the app should work out of the box. Just to make sure the app works when you run yarn start on local host right? When you run yarn run prod, you should get a similar folder as you get with run start. So all the files themes.json, config.json should be there. If you don't get them then there is something else wrong here, are you sure the "yarn run" command executes correctly?

Comment: When I run "yarn run prod" no error is reported and the folder "prod" is finally created. But I can't understand if contents folder are correct !? It would be useful to have a sample folder (prod) that works to make comparisons, because the QWC2 documentation is not very clear on this topic.
Unfortunately the only alternative I have is to proceed by trial and error ...